# Create Website in Windows Azure

Tags: provider-hosted-app, app, azure, azure-service-bus

- We had developed SharePoint Hosted app and as we knew the next step is to create site in Windows Azure for **Appdomain**.
- Due to it's new UI it's very hard to catch the website option . Can
  anyone help me how can we create website in windows Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this steps to create Web App

1. Go to Azure portal -> Create New (+ NEW) by click on this
2. it opens a side window and search for  "Web App"
3. You will get search results on left side window
4. Select Web App and Click on "Create" button

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Please let me know if you have any queries.